# Migrate trigger Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, triggers

People,

I need migrate a Oracle trigger to SQL server, but I could not do.

The trigger in Oracle is very simple:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_teste      
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE  
ON teste  
FOR EACH ROW  
DECLARE  
BEGIN  
:new.id      := (coalesce(:NEW.id,      0));  
:new.vlr_sal := (coalesce(:NEW.vlr_sal, 0.00));  
END;
```

I tried several ways but none successfully!

Thank for help!

Comment: can you post any one way or what exception you are getting?

Comment: Oracle uses PL/SQL, SQL Server uses TSQL -- there's no direct application possible.  What you posted belongs in DEFAULT constraints, not a trigger.

Comment: @OMGPonies: the default declaration will behave differently to what the trigger achieves.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an appropriate use of triggers in any flavour of RDBMS.  The SQL standard allows us to define default values when we create the table using [the DEFAULT constraint syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp).  Both Oracle and SQL Server have this.

Obviously you haven't do this when you created the table.  The good news is we can use ALTER TABLE to add default constraints.  Something like this

```
alter table teste 
   alter column id set default 0
```

That's for SQL Server.  In Oracle it would be:

```
alter table teste 
   modify id default 0
```

---

As the nameless equine points out, a complete replacement for the trigger must include NOT NULL constraints on the affected columns.  If the existing table lacks not null constraints  we can add them using the same syntax as shown above, replacing the DEFAULT clause with `NOT NULL` - or even combining the two clauses in the same statement.

Comment: A default will *not* do the same thing as the trigger. The default only applies if the column is not passed in an insert statement. It will not prevent a a direct update to NULL or explicitely passing a null value. The trigger will (silently) replace that with a non-null value (which is also different to declaring the column `not null`)

Answer (score 1):

My T-SQL is a bit rusty, but something like this should work. Note that SQL server does not have row level triggers, only statement level triggers.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_teste      
ON teste  
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE  
AS 
   update inserted
      set      id = coalesce(id, 0),
          vlr_sal = coalesce(vlr_sal, 0.0)
GO
```

(Not sure if I got missed a semicolon or not. I never understood when SQL Server needs or deosn't need one)

See the manual for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189799%28v=sql.90%29
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms191300%28v=sql.90%29

Comment: This update statement will hit every row in the table.  Hence it could be quite expensive in performance terms.  So while I agree that this is the specific answer the OP is looking for, I still maintain that constraints remain the better implementation.

Comment: @APC: no, it will not. It will only "hit" the ones affected by the DML operation because the `inserted` "virtual table" only contains the modified/inserted rows. SQL Server triggers are fundamentally different than in Oracle (mainly because SQL Server does not have row level triggers)

Comment: Okay, that's an interesting fact to add to my small store of T-SQL knowledge.  But it still doesn'nt make me change my position: anything which can be done without triggers *should* be done without triggers.

Comment: @APC: assuming the intention is to "silently" replace a null value with zero, I don't see a way how this could be achieved without a trigger. A default value will *not* be enough in that case. But apparently Cleber has lost interest in his question.

Comment: The whole idea of "silent replacement" is wrong.  Business rules should be openly declared and interrogable through the data dictionary, as far as possible.  The best way of achieving that happy end is with constraints, not triggers.